# How to add multiple jobs in python Apscheduler Backgroundscheduler?

Tags: python, flask

I have two functions to be called i.e one function to be called every 2 hours and the other function to be called every 3 hours. I tried Backgroundscheduler(Apscheduler), added both the jobs. But somehow the second function is not getting executed. Both the functions are independent and should be run parallelly. Kindly help how to schedule.
[Code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC794.png)

Comment: Did you try a cron-based approach?

Comment: In Backgroundscheduler ?